# Error - Azure Data Factory transfer from SQL Database to Azure Search

Tags: rest, azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-data-factory

I've set up an Azure Data Factory pipeline to transfer the data from one table in our SQL Server Database to our new Azure Search service.  The transfer job continuously fails giving the following error:

> Copy activity encountered a user error at Sink side:
>   GatewayNodeName=SQLMAIN01,ErrorCode=UserErrorAzuerSearchOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error
>   happened when writing data to Azure Search Index
>   '001'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.AzureSearch,''Type=Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException,Message=Operation
>   returned an invalid status code
>   'RequestEntityTooLarge',Source=Microsoft.Azure.Search,'.

From what I've read thus far, Request Entity Too Large error is a standard HTTP error 413 found inside REST API.  Of all the research I've done though, nothing helps me understand how I can truly diagnose and resolve this error.

Has anyone dealt with this with specific context to Azure?  I would like to find out how to get all of our database data into our Azure Search service.  If there are adjustments that can be made on the Azure side to increase the allowed request size, the process for doing so certainly is not readily-available anywhere I've seen on the internet nor in the Azure documentation.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that the batch size written by Azure Search sink into Azure Search is too large. The default batch size is 1000 documents (rows). You can decrease it to a value that balances size and performance by using **writeBatchSize** property of the Azure Search sink. See [Copy Activity Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-search-connector#copy-activity-properties) in [Push data to an Azure Search index by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-search-connector) article.

For example, **writeBatchSize** can be configured on the sink as follows:

`"sink": { "type": "AzureSearchIndexSink", "writeBatchSize": 200 }`

Comment: Would this writeBatchSize be added to the Linked Service, the Input Dataset, the Output Dataset, or the Pipeline?  Further,would I be able to do this from within the Azure Portal UI by using the Add Activity button and adding to the existing JSON code?

Comment: @Stpete111, added an example to the answer.